# How to replace fragments using NavigationGraph in NestedFragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation-graph

Below I have mentioned a hierarchy of multiple nested fragments where I need to replace and add new fragments as child fragments. So I have completed to show `BottomNavigationView` but whenever I tried to load a fragment inside that I face `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
MainActivity
|- MainNavHost
   |- MainFragment
   |  |- NestedNavHost
   |  |  |-NestedContentFragment1
   |  |  |-NestedContentFragment2
   |  |  |-NestedContentFragment3
   |  |
   |  |- BottomNavigationView
   |
   |- OtherFragment
```

The error looks like

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.pkg:id/action_mainFragment_to_accountFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.ipkg:id/navigation_main_tab_fragment) class=com.pkg.MainTabFragment
```

Here `MainTabFragment` is the fragment where I'm displaying the `BottomNavigationView`.

`res/layout/fragment_main_tab.xml`

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_view_selector"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

`res/navigation/nav_graph_main.xml`

`<include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_bottom_nav_view" />`

```
    <action
    android:id="@+id/global_action_pop_to_main_menu"
    app:destination="@id/nav_graph_main_tab"
    app:popUpTo="@id/nav_landing_graph"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

`res/navigation/nav_graph_bottom_nav_view.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph_bottom_nav_view"
app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.pkg.ui.mainTab.MainFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/frag_main">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_accountFragment"
        app:destination="@id/accountFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_right_in"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_left_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_left_in"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_right_out" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_homeFragment"
        app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_right_in"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_left_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_left_in"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_right_out" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_moreFragment"
        app:destination="@id/moreFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_right_in"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_left_out"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_left_in"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_right_out" />

</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/accountFragment"
    android:name="com.pkg.ui.mainTab.AccountFragment"
    android:label="@string/account"
    tools:layout="@layout/frag_main">
</navigation>
```

And I'm trying to replace it from kotlin class as

```
R.id.account -> {
                findNavController().navigate(
                    R.id.action_mainFragment_to_accountFragment)
                return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
            }
```

Hope, my query is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this, here you can find official realization of navComponent menu

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample

Comment: For activity, it's fine. Face issue when nested fragments hierarchy starts.